# Select Box .val() Issue Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, select

I'm sending an Ajax call to the Database to get data to populate and create an existing Select Box.

After the select is created by using `jQuery.html()`, I am trying to pre-set the select box's value.  However, setting the value does not work all the time, and sometimes leaves the Select Box as the Default Option of "Select One" / -1 ONLY in IE8.  Another thing to add is that I am making the Select Box viewable by using

```
$("#selectBox").css('display', 'block')
```

I am using `jQuery.val()`.

I have tried `$("#selectBox").val(id)`

AND

```
$("#selectBox").find('option[value=' + id + ']').prop('selected', true);
```

BUT both present the same inconsistent results I have been running into.

Comment: I have tried .val(id).  How would I use .text(), given that i have an ID. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#selectBox").find('option[value="' + id + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

you can try this, and you must make sure `id` is the option's `value attribute`
Or you must make sure the option have completely loaded before you use

> $("#selectBox").val(id)